# Scheduled report not showing up in email

Tags: email, reporting, scheduled

I have a scheduled report that was supposed to be sent to four recepients, me being one of them. None of us have been getting it. I set it to just me and then went through the email logs. In the logs I see both an R and a D record for the report email, but I still don't have it in my inbox. From what I understand D means that my mail provider has acknowledged it received it, but it doesn't me I would have received it. I checked the spam folder and nothing is showing up in there. I also did the delivery test in Salesforce and got like ~40 test emails, so I know that's fine. My mail provider is Google Apps for Business.

Is there something else I can do to make it work? Other reports to the same users are delivered fine. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't speak for Google Apps for Business but I have seen elsewhere that a company's spam filter is catching it and tossing it long before it ever reaches your mailbox - in my use case, the company spam filter detected it as having a phrase that could be considered porn